# Replace XSLT attribute value without specifying attribute name twice

Tags: xslt

The following XSLT template updates the `bar` attribute withing the foo `element`.

```
<xsl:template match='foo/@bar'>
  <xsl:attribute name='bar'>New value</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Is it possible to remove the duplicated bar name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `name()` function to output the `bar` attribute name dynamically.

```
<xsl:template match='foo/@bar'>
  <xsl:attribute name='{name()}'>New value</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```